# open new tab as same user?

Tags: command-line, sudo, gnome-terminal, user-management, prompt

I often use `sudo` to administer other users on my system.

How can I open a new tab in gnome-terminal with the same user name? Usually, when I open a new tab, I need to run `sudo su THEUSER` again.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to log out and login as root.

Comment: @StarOS How does this make running `su USERNAME` unecessary?

Comment: It becomes root everytime you use the terminal in the root account, that's obvious.

Comment: He is not su'ing to root, though. He is using sudo so to bypass entering the other user's password

Answer (score 2):

After first using

```
sudo -i TheUser
```

Do

```
gnome-terminal &
```

This will launch a new instance of the terminal under the new user, and you can open as many new tabs as you want.